# Piezo element lifespan in vibration environment

Tags: sensor, piezo, damage, vibration

Can anybody guess or does anyone know what lifespan can be expected of this piezoelectric sensor - https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10293 - with a weight glued to it and used inside a passenger vehicle ?

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: That'll be hard to guess. I guess mechanical reliability will depend very much on the weight and the mounting, as well as how well you're able to protect the cables and solder joints. If you need the reliability, dedicated, enclosed vibration sensors are probably a better choice.

Comment: That page also has [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9197) on it. Why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: @DaveTweed tried it. It is much too insensitive for my purposes.